# How can I deploy a docker container to heroku using terraform?

Tags: docker, heroku, containers, terraform

I'm trying to deploy a containerised nextJS application to Heroku via terraform.

I'm able to deploy successfully **without** using containers with this:

```
provider "heroku" {
 email = var.HEROKU_EMAIL
}

resource "heroku_app" "app" {
    name = var.app_name
    region = "eu"
}

resource "heroku_build" "nextjs" {
    app = heroku_app.app.id
    buildpacks = ["https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs"]

    source = {
        path = "./app"
    }
}

resource "heroku_formation" "app" {
    app = heroku_app.app.id
    type= "web"
    quantity = 1
    size = "Free"
    depends_on = [heroku_app.app]
}
```

Looking at the [terraform documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/heroku/r/build.html#building-with-docker) it looks as if I can set the Heroku stack to `container` with:

```
resource "heroku_app" "app" {
    name = var.app_name
    region = "eu"
    stack = "container"
}
```

and i've created a simple `heroku.yml`:

```
build:
    docker:
        web: Dockerfile
run: 
    web: npm build && npm start
```

It's unclear however what the "source" should be in `heroku_build` and currently i'm getting:

```
Error: error retrieving formation: Get https://api.heroku.com/apps/<app-name>/formation/xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx: Couldn't find that app.
```

[This github issue](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-heroku/issues/201) is open with a related question but it doesn't help me much in understanding

Answer (score 1):

You need a Dockerfile, to tell Heroku how to build the Docker image:

```
FROM node:12
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

Then, for the heroku_build:

```
resource "heroku_build" "this" {
  app = heroku_app.this.name

  source = {
    path =  "."
  }
}
```

This way, you will "push" the current folder (.) to Heroku, it will find the heroku.yml and create the Docker image.

Comment: This was helpful! For me, I had to point to a tarball containing those two files.